# Word wrap in ons-modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

Suppose I want to show a very long string in a modal view.

Currently I can set the text dynamically via `angular.element(...).html(...);`. However, the container does not wrap the text at all but **making the modal view scrollable** in order to accomodate that very long string.

Here is how I set up the modal view:

```
<body>
    ...
    <ons-modal var="modalDialog">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-information-circled" size="3x" spin="false"></ons-icon>
        <br><br><div>Original text, can be replaced via jqlite.</div>
        <br><br><ons-button ng-click="modalDialog.hide()">Got it!</ons-button>
    </ons-modal>
    ...
</body>
```

[image]

I have tried the following methods without success:

- Use an extra `<div>` to wrap up the display contents.
- Use an extra `<p>` to wrap up the long string.
- Set the CSS of my elements with `word-wrap: 'break-word'` and `word-break: 'break-all'`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried white-space: normal;

Comment: @srekoble Thanks, I will try these out. But how do I create a fiddle with Onsen-UI activated?

Comment: it's difficult to provide you with a solution if we can't inspect your issue. Dunno how can you insert it to fiddle :/

Comment: @srekoble Screenshot and code snippet provided. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu could try `white-space: normal` hope that it helps